# VBA: How to pop up a messagebox when activecell.value having a division error

Tags: excel, vba

How to set up a message box popup when an active cell value is #DIV/0!

```
Dim GP
GP = "=(" & "Sheet1_Revenue!" & INR1Value & "-" & "Sheet2_Cost!" & INR2Value & ")/" & "Sheet1_Revenue!" & INR1Value

Sheets("Sheet2_Cost").Cells(I + 3, J).Select
ActiveCell = GP
  Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
  With Selection.Interior
                .Color = 65535
  End With

If ActiveCell.Value = "#DIV/0!" Then
    MsgBox "Not an Error: Kindly feed INR values under Sheet1_Revenue"
End If
```

I tried `If ActiveCell.Value =` as well as `If GP.Value =` but both are not working please help me to understand how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You may try `If IsError(ActiveCell) Then` instead. Also, why not check the divisor value first and raise the error before actually dividing by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "#DIV/0!" Then
```

with:

```
If ActiveCell.Text = "#DIV/0!" Then
```

Say we start with:

[image]

This code:

```
Sub ErrorGrabber()
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

but this code:

```
Sub ErrorGrabber()
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Text
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Excel shows you the value "#DIV/0!" when your are divide a number into Zero.... but this value isn't a string....
your if-statement should be in the main part of programming like this example

```
dim a as single, b as single, ans ans single
if b = 0 then
msgbox "...."
else
ans = a / b
end if
```

Comment: thank you @Ammar Abou Zor, this is not practical for me because my code sets formula using some fields from sheet 1 & 2 therefore unless user feeds the values there, this field will show like this. And I don't want user try's to update it in an assumption that this is an error. And this message just guides him so that he won't get panic :) anyway thanks, as of now ''.Text'' worked perfectly for me...

Answer (score 1):

To "trap" a `"#DIV/0!"`  is a 2-step code:

```
If IsError(ActiveCell.Value) Then ' first check if cells contains an error
    If ActiveCell.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then ' check the type of error
        MsgBox "Not an Error: Kindly feed INR values under Sheet1_Revenue"
    End If
End If
```

However, I think the best method is to check the value of the value of the Divisor, before performing the division.

**Note**: there is no need to use `ActiveCell`, you can run your code directly on the fully qualified Range:

```
With Sheets("Sheet2_Cost").Cells(I + 3, J)
    .Value = GP
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    With .Interior
        .Color = 65535
    End With
End With
```